# How do I show Select Box Results that are related to another Select Box in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display truck models that are only related to the selected truck.

For example: https://www.cargurus.com/ & https://www.truecar.com/trade/ (Make & Model Tab)

[cargurus example #1][1]
[cargurus example #2][1]

This is what I have so far, I just don't know how to implement it with the select box below:

```
const trucks = [
    {
  id: "FordTruck",
  make: "Ford",
  models: [
    "F450",
    "F550",
    "F650"
    ]
  },
  {
  id: "DodgeTruck",
  make: "Dodge",
  models: [
    "4400",
    "4500",
    "4600"
    ]
  },
 ]

// Find Dodge Make in trucks array
    const FindDodgeMake = trucks.filter( obj => obj.make === "Dodge" ).map( obj => obj.make );

// Find Ford Make in trucks array
    const FindFordMake = trucks.filter( obj => obj.make === "Ford" ).map( obj => obj.make );

// Turn FindDodgeMake into a string
    const DodgeMake = FindDodgeMake.toString();

// Turn FindFordMake into a string
    const FordMake = FindFordMake.toString();

// Find the Dodge Models when truck = Dodge
    const FindDodgeModels = trucks.filter(truckMake => truckMake.make === "Dodge").map(truckMake => truckMake.models);

// Find the Ford Models when truck = Ford
    const FindFordModels = trucks.filter(truckMake => truckMake.make === "Ford").map(truckMake => truckMake.models);

// Console Log to see if it works
console.log(FordMake);
console.log(DodgeMake);
console.log(FindDodgeModels);
console.log(FindFordModels);

// If truck make = any of the makes then console log the models of that specific truck
function SelectModel(make) {
    if (make ===  FordMake) {
    console.log("Here are the ford models: " + FindFordModels);
  } else if (make === DodgeMake){
    console.log("Here are the dodge models: " + FindDodgeModels);
  } else {
    console.log("Sorry no results")
  }
}

// You can test it with Dodge & Ford, & it works. If you put in another make it will tell you no results
SelectModel("Dodge");

// The above logic I built in JsFiddle, I need to implement that into this next.js file below
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Listbox } from "@headlessui/react";
    
    
// You can select the make in trucks.make 
export default function NewTruckPost() {
  const [selectedTruckMake, setSelectedTruckMake] = useState(trucks[0]);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Listbox value={selectedTruckMake} onChange={setSelectedTruckMake}>
        <Listbox.Button>{selectedTruckMake.make}</Listbox.Button>
        <Listbox.Options>
          {trucks.map((truck) => (
            <Listbox.Option key={truck.id} value={truck}>
              {truck.make}
            </Listbox.Option>
          ))}
        </Listbox.Options>
      </Listbox>
    </Layout>
  );
}

 <Listbox>
 // is disabled until truck make is selected
 // enable when truck make is selected
 // return truck models related only to the truck make
 </Listbox>
```

Now for the part, I am stuck on. I am using react with next.js and headless ui for the listbox.

Currently I can select a Make in the trucks array but now I need to implement the logic above into the react component in another listbox.

I think I need to do the following:

- IF (setSelectedMake === FordMake)
- enable truck model selectbox
- return FindFordModels

Comment: Loop over `selectedTruckMake.model` in another Listbox, and is this what you want ?

Comment: Hi jack I edited my post to make it clearer on what I am trying to do in a react component. Hope that helps.